# require or import in forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
   const basePoints = {}
```

which I need to fill with json files. Currently I do:

```
   import WH11 from 'assets/WH11';
   const basePoints = { WH11}
```

I have like a dozen of such Json files but only 2-3 can be used at a given time. INstead of importing and loading all the JSON files i don't need, I want to require/import based on a config file as shown below:

and my config.js:

```
  const config = {
        basePoints: {
              "WH11": "West Gate",
              "WH12": "West Gate Back Drop"
         }

       }
```

WH11, WH12 etc basically exist in json format in my assets directory:

assets/basepoints/WH11.json

```
     {
       "startingID" : 198

      }
```

etc. Now there can a dozen or more of such json files. The user just adds the ones to be used for the month in config.js.

Is there a way to require/import the json file based on the config file. The app can't compile if I do:

```
     Object.keys(config.basePoints).forEach(key => {
          basePoints[key] = require('../assets/basepoints/' + key + '.json');

        });
```

the error is unexpected require().

Comment: How are you "compiling the app"? Where does this code run?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the latest ES2020 feature - Dynamic Import

Syntax -

```
import('/modules/<module_name>')
  .then(module => {
    //
  })
  .catch(err => {
    //
  });
```

You can learn more about it in this MDN document (scroll down to the dynamic import section) -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import